# How do I resolve missing content type references from uninstalled modules?

Tags: 7, nodes

In my previous setup of my site, I installed a bunch of modules and had them uninstalled. But now I have many orphaned or missing **content types** that still resides in the database somewhere. Below is what is displayed on the Field list page where its trying to reference these non-existent content types. Is there a place where I can go to clean this up? Which tables would I be looking into? And if I were to delete these entries where else would I have to delete it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this probably is happening because you've deleted the module from sites/all/modules before uninstalling it correctly via drupal / or the module you have installed did not provided the code to uninstall it from database. Based in this, you can try to install the module again and then, disable it first, then uninstall it, and then delete it from the sites/all/modules. And don't forget to clear the cache

If the problem persist, i think you can always delet the tables individually from phpmyadmin.
Let me know if the problem persists. So, then i can analyze it with you

Comment: they are uninstalled properly.. i know for a fact that ubercart leaves orphaned data within the database. like say the product_kit content type. there are still references to it somewhere.

Comment: So, i think that you have to analyse the database manually. You can try Navicat or MySql benchmark and delect the orphaned data manually. But don't forget to backup your database before and make sure that your sql backup file is really working.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to manually delete a content type by constructing the URL by hand. For example, to remove the "forum" type, visit `admin/structure/types/manage/forum/delete`. I have had success with this method in the past. As @hailton says elsewhere, take a backup first.